# Loop Over Names of Nested Lists to Create One Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, nested-lists

I have the following, which creates three nested lists for each security's historical prices, such as
Price$F for Ford.

```
library(tseries)

tickers <- c('F','MSFT','GOOG')
 
end = Sys.Date()-1
Price <- list()
for(i in tickers){
  Price[[i]] <- get.hist.quote(i, end = Sys.Date()-1, 
                  quote = c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Adjusted", "Volume"))
}
```

I would like to get a data frame that...

1. Stacks all the lists.
2. Adds a column for the securities ticker symbol/name.
3. Add the date as a column.

So the output would look

[image]

Note that I can't use `tidyquant` etc. here, but I don't necessarily have to have the lists in the first place.

Comment: Do you need `Reduce(merge, Price)`

Answer (score 0):

Since you want one combined dataframe we can convert the `zoo` object to dataframe using `fortify.zoo` and add a new column of names of list using `imap`.

```
library(purrr)
Result <- imap_dfr(Price, ~.x %>% zoo::fortify.zoo() %>% mutate(Symbol= .y))


head(Result)
#       Index     Open     High      Low    Close Adjusted  Volume Symbol
#1 1991-01-02 4.812811 4.881240 4.630335 4.790002 1.689240 3109100      F
#2 1991-01-03 4.767192 4.858430 4.744383 4.744383 1.673152 3173400      F
#3 1991-01-04 4.767192 4.881240 4.744383 4.835621 1.705328 3211700      F
#4 1991-01-07 4.790002 4.790002 4.653145 4.653145 1.640976 3373900      F
#5 1991-01-08 4.698764 4.721573 4.630335 4.653145 1.640976 3045600      F
#6 1991-01-09 4.744383 4.812811 4.584716 4.584716 1.616845 5636200      F

tail(Result)
#           Index    Open     High      Low   Close Adjusted  Volume Symbol
#18902 2020-07-17 1521.62 1523.440 1498.420 1515.55  1515.55 1456700   GOOG
#18903 2020-07-20 1515.26 1570.290 1503.600 1565.72  1565.72 1557300   GOOG
#18904 2020-07-21 1586.99 1586.990 1554.280 1558.42  1558.42 1218600   GOOG
#18905 2020-07-22 1560.50 1570.000 1546.100 1568.49  1568.49  932000   GOOG
#18906 2020-07-23 1566.97 1571.870 1507.392 1515.68  1515.68 1627600   GOOG
#18907 2020-07-24 1498.93 1517.636 1488.400 1511.87  1511.87 1544000   GOOG
```